# Repaint() is not called from inside a running thread java

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame on to which i have a JPanel, and i am trying to do some free hand drawing on to it using paintComponent(). 
Now, i change the xPOS and yPOS variable from inside the mouseDragged method, and then calls the repaint(), so it works fine

```
//**PROGRAM 1**-My DrawPanel Class
  public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener{
    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;
    String message;
    DrawPanel(){
        //constructor ini
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setBackground(Color.green);
        setSize(500, 400);
        setBounds(10, 10, 500, 400);
        }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.fillOval(xpos, ypos, 5, 5);
      }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
     xpos= arg0.getX();
         ypos= arg0.getY();
    //   s.SendData(xpos,ypos);
        repaint();
    }

    public void run() {

        try{
            while((message = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                int in = message.indexOf("#");
                xpos = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(0, in));
                ypos = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(in+1));
                System.out.print(xpos+" "+ypos);

                repaint();
            }}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
```

i have a thread, which accepts some new co-ordinates from some other java program thru socket, i am able to accept them , my

```
System.out.print(xpos+" "+ypos);
```

works fine, but the repaint() method just after that, doesn't seem to work, no error, nothing happens.

FYI, the other java program i mentioned, has the same kind of structure, and i send the co-ordinates from this java program to that one,

```
//   s.SendData(xpos,ypos);
```

and that one is able to call the repaint() method from inside the thread.
but just can;t seem to understand, why it is not happening in this one.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**SSCCE** PaintBrushServer

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
public class PaintBrush {

DrawPanel dr = new DrawPanel();
 myFrame mf;
 Graphics g1;
 boolean flag=false;
 server s;
 BufferedReader reader;
PaintBrush(){
myFrame mf = new myFrame();
s = new server();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new PaintBrush();
   }

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{
ButtonPanel(){
    add(new myButton());
}
 }

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener{

int xpos = 0;
 int ypos = 0;
String message;

DrawPanel(){
    //constructor ini
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.green);
    setSize(500, 400);
    setBounds(10, 10, 500, 400);
    //s = new server();

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillOval(xpos, ypos, 5, 5);

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
     xpos= arg0.getX();
     ypos= arg0.getY();
     s.SendData(xpos,ypos);
    repaint();
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try{

        while((message = reader.readLine())!=null) {

            int in = message.indexOf("#");
            xpos = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(0, in));
            ypos = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(in+1));
           // System.out.print(xpos+" "+ypos);
           repaint();
        }}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}




}
 public class myFrame extends JFrame{
 myFrame(){
     DrawPanel dr = new DrawPanel();
    //setBackground(Color.black); 
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setVisible(true);
    setSize(665,490);
    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,dr);
    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new ButtonPanel());
 }
}public class myButton extends JButton{

 myButton(){
     setText("PaintBrushServer");
    // addActionListener(new listen());

 }

 }

public class server {
  ServerSocket ssock;
 Socket clientSocket;
 PrintWriter writer;
 DataOutputStream os = null;
 server(){
     //ini server
      try {
        ssock = new ServerSocket(42422);
        System.out.println("waiting");
        clientSocket = ssock.accept();
        System.out.println(clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress()+" connected\n");
        //writer = new PrintWriter(.getOutputStream());
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        new Thread(dr).start();
      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 public void SendData(int x, int y){
    try{ 
        os.writeBytes(x+"#"+y+"\n");
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
 }

}
}
```

**SSCCE-PaintBrushClient**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Client {
int xpos = 0;
int ypos = 0;
Boolean flag = false;
ClientConnect cc ;
DataOutputStream os = null;

BufferedReader reader;
Client(){
//server connect
ClientConnect cc = new ClientConnect();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

new Client();
}

public class ClientConnect {
private Socket sock;
String message;
ClientConnect(){
   try {
    sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 42422);
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
    reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
    os = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
     //sr = new ServerReader();
     //sr.start();
    new myFrame();

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}}

public void SendData(int x, int y){
try{ 
    os.writeBytes(x+"#"+y+"\n");
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener{

 String message;
DrawPanel(){
    //constructor ini
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.green);
    setSize(500, 400);
    setBounds(10, 10, 500, 400);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillOval(xpos, ypos, 5, 5);

}

@Override
public void run() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       try{

        while((message = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            int in = message.indexOf("#");
            xpos = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(0, in));
            ypos = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(in+1));
            //System.out.println(message);
            System.out.println(xpos+" "+ypos);
            repaint();

        }}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     xpos= arg0.getX();
     ypos= arg0.getY();
     //flag = true;
     //System.out.println(xpos);
     //SendData(xpos,ypos);
    repaint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
}
 public class myButton extends JButton{
 myButton(){
 setText("PaintBrushClient");
 //addActionListener(new listen());
 }
 }
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{
ButtonPanel(){
    add(new myButton());
}
}

public class myFrame extends JFrame{
 myFrame(){
 DrawPanel dr = new DrawPanel();
 new Thread(dr).start();
setResizable(false);
 setBackground(Color.black); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(665,490);
    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,dr);
    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new ButtonPanel());


 }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not blocking the EDT? If so, then any calls to repaint() would be useless since the repaint() is just another Event on the AWT-EventQueue

Comment: Could it be a visibility issue - in other words: you modify `xpos` and `ypos` in a different thread without proper synchronization and your `paintComponent()` method does not see the updated values?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  i am not sure about that, as i said i have another java program, which connects to this thru sockets and i send coordinates to it, and it does exactly the same, take coordinated inside the thread, call repaint(), all i want to do is the reverse, so now that java program should be able to send the coordinates and it is accepted here and drawn. if it is happening there, y can't here..?

Comment: Could you provide a SSCCE since i don't see any problems with the part of code you have presented - it works fine for me. Seems the problem is somewhere outside of the panel...

Comment: You should probably post the code where you create your Thread that invokes the run method

Comment: @Nikhar Sharma blocked EDT by using Thread.sleep(int),

Comment: @Guillaume Polet I think answer by assylias (users with rep >10k can see deleted answers) could be correct if is there used Thread.sleep(), sure correct suggestion could be use Swing Timer instead of Runnable#Thread :-)

Comment: @mKorbel i didn't used that, yes i tried it, but i removed that later.

Comment: At least one thing is a problem: the access to xpos and ypos should be `synchronized` because they are shared by different Threads.

Comment: @Nikhar Sharma now that make me sence, use SwingWorker for ServerSocket

Comment: @mKorbel If I remember correctly the solution proposed by assylias was to invoke repaint in an invokeLater() call. This is not necessary (repaint will automatically post an Event on the EventQueue which will in turn be dispatched in the EDT). I don't see any Thread.sleep, and one of my first comment was actually about blocking the EDT. I believe a lot more that his coordinates members are shared with different threads but not synched

Comment: @GuillaumePolet you can see my other java program which connects with this one, i don't get any problem there.

Comment: *"THIS HAS SAME.."*  Stop SHOUTING at us!  And post an SSCCE.

Comment: You seem to be good at ignoring the things you don't want to address, so here is something I want all of your attention on.  **POST AN SSCCE!**

Comment: @AndrewThompson  What i am trying to accomplish here is, on Program 1, i draw something, which thru sockets, is drawn on the Program 2, which works fine. But when i try to do the reverse, that i draw on program 2 and thru sockets it gets drawn on Program 1, i get the data thru streams, but the repaint() method is not called somehow.

Comment: @AndrewThompson and i completely forgot that writing in caps was considered shouting, did'nt meant it.

Comment: *"What i am trying to accomplish here.."*  I'll read descriptions like that directly after compiling & running the SSCCE ( not shouting, just stating an abbreviation ;).

Comment: @AndrewThompson added SSCCE, sorry for the delay.

Comment: try calling repaint in your thread with it's parent because simply calling repaint won't have the same instance as your gui, something like, yourPanel.repaint() etc

Comment: `Client.DrawPanel is not abstract and does not override abstract method..` :(

Comment: *"..just add the unimplemented methods."*  I suggest you actually read the document on the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  If you've already read it, read it again.  Good luck with it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson man..sorry..its done, i have added...

Comment: @AndrewThompson as always, you are correct, an SSCCE helped to solve the issue. I can only worship your pugnacity on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer to above problem of repaint() method not called from inside the thread on PaintBrushServer, while it is being called on PaintBrushClient is....

Just remove the `DrawPanel dr = new DrawPanel();` from myFrame(JFrame) class, as i already did that in the beginning.

Thanks all for their comments and suggestions, also @andrewThompson i now know how to provide a good SSCCE..lol

Answer (score 2):

1. You never start a thread to read the data (oh you do in the server. Why post duplicate code four times, except for some commented out lines ><)
2. xpos/ypos updates in one thread might not be seen by another. At
   least they should be volatile, but I would prefer a setXYPosition()
   method:

   ```
   public synchronized void setXYPosition(int x, int y) {
     this.xpos = x;
     this.ypos = y;
     repaint();
   }
   ```
3. Why are you writing bytes and reading (character) lines?
4. revalidate() like suggested by others is not needed since you are
   painting directly, not change the layout/component hierarchy.

Comment: noted the Synchronized thing.. 3rd one yes, is stupid, i know, but i was more onto achieving what i had in mind, i was planing to change that in future, this was just an experiment i took to understand things more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I eventually got it to work on my computer so I guess this might interest you:

Two things here:

1. When you override `paintComponent`, you should still call super: `super.paintComponents(g);` before drawing on top of the rest.
2. Make your xpos ypos `volatile` since you access them from separate threads.

Also there is a missing overriden method in of your code. Eventually, I fixed it all up and I could draw in one frame while seeing it painted in both (having launched the 2 different program).

I am not going to rant about the design and others stuffs. There are other posts with nice suggestions.

One only thing, which i think has not been mentionned, but if you have classes shared between two programs .Put them in another file and use it several times instead of copy/pasting them. This is the case for several of your classes. And if there is only a slight difference between the two, just add a parameter that you can change to indicate which case you are in.

OK, I am ranting, but it is actually when you draw in your server frame, that the clients reacts and draws the same thing. Personnally, I would have called the Client a Server and the Server a Client in your case. Usually, the Server "listens" for clients, and in this case where you draw is your client and where you see it replicated is your server, but that's just semantics.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for help. the 1st thing: i removed the super.paintComponent(g) because with it i think the background is refreshed everytime i call repaint(), and thus my previous drawing is lost. 2nd thing:i have already noted that, and will definitely implement it. 3rd: There could be lot of issue with this program, but i wanted to create a simple basic understandable program for my knowledge, and also, i don't have any classes that are shared between 2 program, those 2 are entirely different program(have the same kind of content though).

Comment: So i just want to ask this, were u able to draw on PaintBrushClient(2nd Program) one, and was automatically getting drawn on PaintBrushServer(1st Program)?. Also i called them server and client just because PaintBrushServer has a ServerSocket coding.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for all your suggestions,it is working now,it was a very stupid mistake of mine. but thanks to that mistake, i found so many issues in my coding.

Answer (score 1):

1) use `JTextArea` for displaying incoming `String` or `Object` from `ServerSocked`, in the case that you planing to use `Stylled Text`, then look at `JTextPane`

2) use `SwingWorker` for open, read and close (in the `finally block`) of `Socket`, there are two options:

- use `publish()` or `process()` for distribute incoming `Chars`, `String` or `Object` from `Socket`, since is declared that output will be on EDT, I'd to suggest wrap method `JTextCompoent#append` into `invokeLater`
- easier could be waiting for `Socked` if is ended and in the `done()` put `String` or `Object` to the desired `JComponent`

4) sure is possible use `Runnable#Thread` for distributing `String` or `Object` from `Socket` to the Swing GUI, but I'd suggestint output must be wrapped into `invokeLater`,

3) a few very good code about `Socket + SwingWorker + JTextArea` on this forum

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a thread that accepts coordinates, is this the Event Dispatch Thread? If so then it may be blocking any updates to the UI.

Comment: no it is just a normal thread. but as i said, this thing is working perfectly in other java program. y this here?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SwingUtilities.invokelater( ... )` to make updates to your UI while you are making some other calculations. In your case

```
repaint()
```

or even better

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

should be called inside the `invokeLater` runnable implementation.

Comment: Actually repaint() can be called from any Thread because it is Thread-safe. No point in using revalidate() if the hierarchy of components does not change

Comment: Actually both the methods are thread safe, so you can use them anywhere, see [Java Docs](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html#exceptions), for more info :-)